# Prestashop blockcategories: save expanded and collapsed while browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I am using PrestaShop 1.5.6.1 and I am using blockcategories module (with dynamic property set on), to display my categories. The problem is that, if I expand few categories while I am on main page and then I go to another page, for example cart, all categories in blockcategories collapses. What I want to do: 
I have categories, lets say: cat1, cat2, cat3 and cat4. 
On main page I collapse cat2, cat3 and expand cat1, cat4
When I go to Cart page, cat2 and cat3 should be collapsed and cat1, cat4 should be expanded.

Now when i go to cart (or any other page), all categories are collapsed and I have to expand them again, if I want to see subcategories. It's really irritating.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope I explained everything comprehensibly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't explain everything comprehensibly. Please give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you already have tried and why that's not working and preferably some pictures (Paint sketches are fine) showing what you want to happen vs. what's actually happening.

Comment: I tried to clean cache, but that didn't help. I am not sure if it is a bug. What I want is if I expand some categories, it should be expanded while I am browsing my website. Now if i expand some categories and I click on any link, it collapses.

Comment: What I meant to ask was what code you had already tried to use, and why that didn't work.

Comment: I am using pure blockcategories installation. As I said, I am not sure if it is a bug, or it's supposed to be. It's first time I have a deal with PrestaShop, so it's hard even to figure out where should I start to look up for a problem.

Comment: I'm still not understanding. Is this not a programming question?

Comment: I found a solution. The bug was:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.grower').trigger('click')
});
</script>
code in blockcategories.tpl file.